# What is the uncured pork belly called?

Tags: bacon

wiki says

> Bacon is a type of salt-cured pork ... typically from the pork belly.

What is the uncured pork belly called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In all seriousness, it's called pork belly.

Comment: sometimes it's sold as "uncured bacon", which is an oxymoron, but maybe more marketable than "pork belly".